# Regex: group as an array of mathches with CR in between

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am trying to parse in Python a file with information in this format

```
aaa    111(zzz)
       222
       333
bbb    555
       111
```

this is baically a way to relate `aaa` with `111`, `222` and `333` (a kind of reference table). Note that `zzz` is optional although this is not important right now.

What I am trying to get is something like this:

**Match 1**

- group 1. 'aaa'
- group 2. ['111', '222', '333']

**Match 2**

- group 1. 'bbb'
- group 2. ['555', '111']

What I am struggling with is how to make `group 2` as an array. Although I might be going in the wrong way.

Could somebody light me on this?

This is my current [attempt](https://regex101.com/r/rVobRv/1). It is not even close to what I try to achieve, though.

**Update**

I will use Python and most probably `re` as regex module.

Comment: What is the language? Group capture stack is only supported by .NET and PyPi regex libraries. In all other cases, match the blocks capturing the `aaa` into Group 1, the rest of the block into Group 2, and then split the Group 2 value with whitespaces.

Comment: Sorry, post updated. I am using Python.

Comment: But are you using `re` or `regex` module?

Comment: I guess I will use re. Haven't yet started as I am still researching how to extract this information on [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Comment: See https://ideone.com/FsKyln. I assume you need to extract all digit chunks from the Group 2. Maybe you need to split with whitespace, then you'd use `split()` - https://ideone.com/wNYu7z

Comment: Simple and simply awesome :). I just stuck because was trying to do all at once. ains! Thanks! I'm gonna try to extract `zzz` now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the blocks capturing the necessary parts into two groups, and then split/extract what you need from Group 2.

```
^(\S+)\s+(.*(?:[\r\n]+ +.*)*)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of the line (due to `re.M`)
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - 1  or more whitespaces
- `(.*(?:[\r\n]+ +.*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:[\r\n]+ +.*)*` - zero or more occurrences of

    - `[\r\n]+` - 1 or more line break chars
    - `+` - one or more spaces (you may replace it with `[^\S\r\n]*` to match any horizontal whitespace)
    - `.*` -  the rest of the line

An [example code](https://ideone.com/FsKyln)

```
import re
s = """aaa    111(zzz)
       222
       333
bbb    555
       111"""
rx= r'^(\S+)\s+(.*(?:[\r\n]+ +.*)*)'
res =[]
for m in re.finditer(rx, s, re.M):
    res.append((m.group(1), re.findall(r"[0-9]+", m.group(2))))
    # res.append((m.group(1), m.group(2).split())) # or split with whitespace
print(res) # => [('aaa', ['111', '222', '333']), ('bbb', ['555', '111'])]
```

Comment: I understand the regex but I still do not get why `rx` "stops" in `bbb`. See [DEMO ](https://regex101.com/r/rVobRv/2).

Comment: I am using `re.M`, thus you must enable the `m` MULTILINE mode at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rVobRv/3).